# Website for packaged audio performance virtual "devices"

Tags: vst

I'm fairly familiar with VSTs, Ableton, and similar stuff.  But all of those require some configuration/setup.  The flexibility allows you to build complex systems, but I'm looking for a "gallery" of virtual audio machines (think of guitar pedals for example) that I just download and immediately start jamming with (on a connected microphone, guitar, or MIDI controller).

This doesn't require any kind of standard -- it could be implemented on a variety of platforms, for example Ableton Live.

So are there any websites where I can look for "ready to use" tools like this?

Comment: I think you are less familiar with VST's than you think you are.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever looked into [Reason](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/)?

While there is room for much configuration and setup, the virtual rack gear has many presets to just jam with.  They've also recently opened up to 3rd party [rack extension](http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/index.cfm?fuseaction=get_article&article=whats-new) developers.

I guess the main reason I mention this option is that, unlike many other plugins, the virtual equipment actually looks and behaves like real equipment.  No menus or dropdowns and such.  Just knobs and faders.  I would guess that that makes it much easier to jam with.

Comment: And can you recommend some websites for preset files for Reason?

Answer (score 0):

KVRAudio lists a ton of VSTs, and are (or at least were at one time) run by the company that makes a device that runs VSTs as a stand-alone (physical) device. I believe they list if the plug-in has a stand-alone mode.

If you want to run any VST as a stand-alone using a free program called SAVIhost - but that only works for instruments. They just updated the software to 32x and 64x.

More and more VSTs are shipping with stand-alone versions. I often use those when I just want to play.

There are a couple of software vendors that do the "stomp-box" metaphore, some of them are stand-alone effects. I believe Native Instruments Guitar Rig will run as a stand alone. reFX has Slayer which can be a set of effects pedals, and reValver by Peavy. Image-Line and TH2 also have a similar products.